# Anonymously ask a question

Tags: feature-request

There is certain questions I want to ask but don't want them being linked to me personally. I know nobody knows me personally, but I want to show this sight to some friends and they can link my account to me.

If this is possible, I think it would be a great benefit to the sight if you could anonymously ask a question. Down-votes and up-votes will still apply to the asker of the question, but their points won't be visibly linked to that question.

So when your viewing a user's page, under the reputation spot, maybe there could be a section that says anonymous questions and it could just say points earned in that area.

Also answers and comments could become anonymous in this way too.

Answer (score 8):

You can always log out of your account, or fire up an anonymous session and ask the question without it being linked to your account.

SE sites (all except SO), all support participation that is not tied to your account.

The other option is that if you have participation that you would rather not be associated with your account (questions or answers), you do have the right (per the content license) to request that your user name be removed (up votes and downvotes will also no longer affect your account).

Obviously this is not "Anonymous" in the sense that it's still tied to your account, just without your name. However, these are the two forms of anonymity that are supported and I do not foresee any additional forms being added.

Comment: You can also create a second account. SE policy is (or was last I checked) to allow this, so long as it's not being used for abusive behavior (i.e. be sure not to vote on your own posts from another account!)